# Getting "TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function" in Node.Js

Tags: node.js

app.js

```
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(200, function(req, res){
  var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var filename = "." + q.pathname;
  fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data){
    if(err)
    {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
        return res.end("404 Not Found!!!");
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

When I try to run it using the command "node app.js", I am getting the following error:

```
events.js:238
    throw new TypeError('"listener" argument must be a function');
    ^

TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function
    at _addListener (events.js:238:11)
    at Server.addListener (events.js:298:10)
    at new Server (_http_server.js:263:10)
    at Object.createServer (http.js:35:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\AngularJS\New folder\app2.js:7:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
```

I tried to find out the solution but wasn't able to resolve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`http.createServer` expects only a `function`, with 2 callback items `(response, request)`. Simply remove `200` from your createServer call or replace it with this:

`http.createServer(function(req, res) { ... }`

You can read more about this here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `200`,
Check below code

```
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var filename = "." + q.pathname;
  fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data){
    if(err)
    {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
        return res.end("404 Not Found!!!");
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```